# Apex VS Code Type Intellisense

Tags: apex, vs-code

I am wondering if anyone knows a way to make "type" intellisense work better when instantiating things like Lists and Maps in VS code for Apex.

I've put a few examples in the images below, but it's slightly frustrating that VS code doesn't know the type I'm trying to instantiate when I've already typed it to the left of my variable name.

[image: List Example1]

[image: Map Example2]

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intellisense isn't that smart. In fact, their [Market](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_types-of-completions) page says so:

> In VS Code, you can enhance your coding with artificial intelligence (AI), such as suggestions for lines of code or entire functions, fast documentation creation, and help creating code-related artifacts like tests.

You're looking for AI-assisted autocompletion. They go by names like Tabnine, Co-Pilot, Einstein, and IntelliCode. These autocompletion tools can not just complete data parameters correctly (at least, most of the time), they can also write code based on comments, comments based on code, write related functions automatically, and even determine what kind of algorithm you're trying to write.

However, if you're going down this road, you should be aware that the limited/free versions are pretty worthless. They're slow and/or only suggest small snippets at a time. The paid versions I've tried are powerful, though, and easily worth the price of admission. Here's a quick screenshot of what I see when I write the exact same code you did:

[image: Autosuggesting the correct type]

Pressing `Tab` will complete the suggestion:

[image: After autocompleting]

This also works with sets and even maps:

[image: Map auto-suggest]

And even nested types:

[image: Nested Map auto-suggest]

Sometimes it does need more than one auto-complete, but it will almost always get it right.

Of course, I'm not saying that feature alone is worth $10-15/month, but it is one of many helpful things you can do. In fact, I estimate it probably increases my productivity by up to 30%, and I can even write algorithms that I'm not familiar with simply by prompting it with comments.

I am not endorsing any specific product, because I believe people should make their own decisions based on their needs. The four named ones above are just ones I'm familiar with or heard of, and there are likely many others out there.

It's not a perfect system, but at least some systems can train on all of your code repos, which helps it mimic your code style better. If you have a repo full of Apex, like I do, it will almost always write correct Apex code with minimal prompting.

Comment: I appreciate the comment! I remember using Visual Studio back in the day to write C# and it always knew which type I wanted. Hopefully VS code will someday as well :)